# How to use react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm using the react native firebase guide to install firebase in my react native app: https://rnfirebase.io/#2-android-setup

The installation has been successful and firebase is connected to my app.

However when I try to import from the SDK, I'm getting an error that it's not found:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'
```

The error reads:

```
Undefined Unable to resolve module 'react-native-firebase' from 'App.js'...
```

As the docs instruct I just used npm install like so:

```
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app
```

And the package is indeed installed. So what could be the reason? Is it not an SDK anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all

Step 2. Delete the node_modules folder: rm -rf node_modules && npm install

Step 3. Reset packager cache: npm start -- --reset-cache

Comment: Thanks but why should I do it, why delete the node_modules folder?

Comment: It's just because sometimes, the packages are using cache and not able to get the current modules. It's a good practice to delete node_modules and reinstall it, to avoid any errors.